# Use state to replace complete object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management

I have beolow code

```
const [data,setData] = useState(obj)
```

Now I am passing this data to some component

```
<comp data={data} />
```

Now When I do below

```
setData(newOBj);
```

then comp does not render again

but when I do something like changing any property it works

```
setData(prev=> ({
      ...prev,
      pOPageIndex: null,
      cCPageIndex: null
    }));
```

How do we replace complete object and make the component render again

Thanks

Comment: This is likely due to how React determines if a component should be re-rendered (in basic terms, only when one of it's props changes). Can you see what happens if you try `setData({...newOBj})`?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you mutate state, in order for a component to re-render, React makes a [shallow comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) with previous state / props, so having a new reference will re-render your component:

```
setData({...newOBj})
```

- See last examples in [Power of not mutating Data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) from React docs